# How to check if a website is up and running without downloading the whole page in python? [Solved]

Tags: html, python-3.x, url, python-requests, web-testing

I need to check if a website is up and running. I have hundreds of links to check. What is the most efficient way to do that? I don't want to download the whole page. Sometimes I encounter with documents with the size of 70MB. I used requests module to do that but it takes too long? Would it help to use stream argument like below?

Edit: I solved by filtering the big files like pdfs.

```
r = requests.get(tarball_url, stream=True)
```

Here is the code I've been using:

```
for website_url in websitelinks:
    try: 
        result = requests.get(website_url, stream=True, timeout=5)
        if result.status_code == 200:
            do_something()
    except Exception:
        pass
```

Comment: My first thought was stream=True when I saw the headline. To speed it up you maybe can multi thread it?

Comment: Instead of calling the HTTP `GET` method, call the `HEAD` method.  I expect that you can do that with `requests.head`.  It will only download the headers for the page, not the entire content.

Comment: Sometimes I encounter 70MB's of document like pdf and it slows that too.

Comment: probably not helpful, but often people have specific link to check health status of an application like `/healthz` - checking each link individually is indeed problematic. Also you might just `ping` those servers to see if they're responsive at all (though in this case you might get a false positive, if only LB is running)